Are Large Symbolic Models (LSMs) being developed, or is symbolic AI still largely separate from LLMs?
I'm curious about the integration of symbolic reasoning into large-scale AI models. We’ve seen incredible advancements in Large Language Models (LLMs) like GPT, which excel at pattern recognition and statistical reasoning. However, LLMs seem to struggle with tasks that require formal logic, rule-based reasoning, and deeper knowledge representation.
My question is:

Are there any developments or research into Large Symbolic Models
(LSMs) that combine the strengths of symbolic AI (formal logic,
rule-based reasoning, etc.) with the statistical capabilities of
LLMs?
Or is symbolic AI still largely treated as a separate domain
in the AI community?

I’m particularly interested in understanding whether hybrid models that integrate both approaches are being pursued and what challenges or advancements exist in this area.

there are some startups working on it, if that answers your question
